# Beamer: having grayed out items due to pause, but skipping over some

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize, pause

I want to have 3 slides, where on the first slide, I have a list of bullet points, and then after the 2nd one, we KEEP the third one looking grayed out, jump to slide 2, where I talk about bullet point 2, and then after we go to slide 3, which is a duplicate of slide 1, but now nothing is grayed out.

Any suggestions?

Slide 1:

1. A \pause
2. B \pause
3. C \pause

Slide 2:

2. Means B is very good.

Slide 3:

1. A
2. B
3. C

Answer (score 4):

`\againframe` is your friend. You need to provide a label to the first frame to be able to recall it later. And an overlay specification to tell `beamer`, which slides should be shown before going to the next frame.

Here I used overlay specifications for the items, because this makes it easier to see, which item is shown on which slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>[label=list]{List}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Point A
\item<2-> Point B
\item<3-> Point C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Explaning Point B}
Stuff on point B
\end{frame}

\againframe<3>{list}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** without `\againframe` you can only repeat the first frame. There just remove all overlay specifications. And the label for the first frame is no longer necessary.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>{List}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Point A
\item<2-> Point B
\item<3-> Point C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Explaning Point B}
Stuff on point B
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{List}
\begin{itemize}
\item Point A
\item Point B
\item Point C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there no simpler way to just change the text to stay grayed out? I am working in markdown beamer environment and do not think I can use \againframe

Comment: @robertevansanders see edit in my answer